# Where does the word "good" come from?

Tags: etymology

According to Google, and a few other sources, "good" was originally the verbal and adjective equivalent of "god" (hence the good news')
but I was wondering where the word originally came from and what is its  etymology.

Answer (score 5):

*Good* does not come from *God*, but probably from Old English *gōd*, which is not the same. Before 900; Middle English (adj., adv., and noun); Old English gōd (adj.); cognate with Dutch goed, German gut, Old Norse gōthr, Gothic goths. The first hand-written English language Bible manuscripts were produced in the 1380's by Wycliffe from the Latin Vulgate, so you can draw your own conclusions. (et vidit *Deus* lucem quod esset *bona* et divisit lucem ac tenebras: And *God* saw the light, that it was *good*: and divided the light from the darkness. Gen 1:4) The word *God* comes from the IndoEuropean root *gal-* "to call out.<sup>[1]</sup> However, ProtoSemetic root found in Hebrew was there as such in Proto-Semitic "*ח ד ה , GH D H (accentuated vowel)". I don't know if that is significant. Many religions have malevolent gods as well as good ones.

> [Good](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=good&searchmode=none): from Old English gōd (with a long "o") "virtuous; desirable; valid; considerable," probably originally "having the right or desirable quality," from Proto-Germanic *gothaz (cognates: Old Norse goðr, Dutch goed, Old High German **guot**, German **gut**, Gothic **goþs**), originally "*fit, adequate, belonging together*," **from PIE root *ghedh- "to unite, be associated, suitable"** (cognates: Old Church Slavonic godu "pleasing time," Russian godnyi "fit, suitable," Old English gædrian "to gather, to take up together"). As an expression of satisfaction, from early 15c.; of children, "well-behaved," by 1690s. - Etymonline

The alleged Indo-European “root” of "good" is ghedh (to unite, join, fit).   That which is united is "good". according to the *Encyclopedia of Indo-European Culture*, Gothic **goþs** meant "good, kind, beautiful", but gives no date.

If I had the OED, I might be able to do more.

<sub>[1] Wondering about Words: D'où viennent les mots anglais ? by Judith Andreyev</sub>

Comment: Gothic words can usually be assumed to be datable to the Gothic Bible by Wulfila, which was written some time around AD 500.

Comment: It really might be from PIE root *ghedh- "to unite, be associated, suitable". In slavic languages there are many words with root "god" meaning "fit well", "good"